# Simple alternative to GNU Readline library not GPL

Tags: c++

I love the GNU readline library, but since it is under a GPL license, I can not use it for commercial software. Do you know alternatives ? I only need the commandline history and auto completion (of customer keywords and files) features. I found this link :

http://github.com/antirez/linenoise

which seem to be a good starting point, but does not have auto completion.

Any suggestions, surely this must be a common task for people building interactive shell commands.

Update :

Upps forgot one important detail it should also run on windows..

Comment: The alternative is to make your software free.  At least, RMS thinks so.

Comment: Technically, you can use it in commercial software, just not proprietary/closed source software. That distinction probably isn't of much help to you though...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lightweight GNU readline alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982633/lightweight-gnu-readline-alternative)

Answer (score 8):

NetBSD has a Readline replacement library called libedit, see http://www.thrysoee.dk/editline/.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't used it, but this http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~mcs/tecla/index.html appears to be  a getline replacement, with a non-restrictive license.