# GNU Auto completion on variables

Tags: c, linux, autocomplete, gnu, libreadline

I'm developing a Linux tool with a prompt in C. I have enabled "function" and "file" completion using GNU library. Now I want to extend the support to "variable" name completion as well. Below is the example for better understanding:

## WORKING OUTPUT:

```
build2:/u/anitha> linux_tool
loading history
tool> 
tool> ***On pressing TAB twice, the functions are prompted***
Display all 251 possibilities? (y or n)
byte(        
dim(    
fncc_fft2d(   
HasValue(      
ifft(
load_csv(
```

## EXPECTED ADDITIONAL SUPPORT:

```
tool> **var_name**=create(2,2)
2x2x1 array of int, bsq format [16 bytes]
0       1
2       3
tool>
tool> ***on pressing TAB twice, I want the variable name to be prompted for auto completion. i.e.**,*
tool> var_
**var_name**
Version(
```

## Code added for auto completion:

```
char ** dv_complete_func(char *text, int start, int end);
char *dv_complete_func_generator(const char*, int);
extern struct _vfuncptr vfunclist[];
  /* This array has the list of functions that the tool can support */

char **
dv_complete_func(char *text, int start, int end)
{
  return rl_completion_matches(text, dv_complete_func_generator);
}


char *dv_complete_func_generator(const char *text, int state) 
{
    static int list_index, len;
    char *name;

    if(!state) {
        list_index =0; 
        len=strlen(text);
    }   

    while((name = vfunclist[list_index++].name)) {
        if(strncmp(name,text,len)==0) {
             char *namedup = strdup(name);
             strcat(namedup,"(");
            return strdup(namedup);
        }   

    }   
    return NULL;
}
```

Let me know if the question is unclear. Please help me with a solution.

Comment: Yes, the question is unclear.

Comment: Show your actual code. You are on the right track. *Show the source code* of your function bound to `rl_attempted_completion_function`. So **edit your question** to improve it a lot.

Comment: I want the "tab completion" to be extended for variables as well. I.e., if I create a variable within my prompt, then "on pressing tab" it should also show the variables apart from the function names.

Comment: Please edit your question (which probably should be *much* longer) to give your actual source code

Comment: While editing, you might find this interesting https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Also the fact that while editing there is a preview of how the question will look like.

Comment: @Krish: I hope your project is open source. Then putting it on [github](http://github.com/) and giving its URL inside your question could be helpful.

Comment: What exact function is put into `rl_attempted_completion_function`  ?

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(Just a guess, since you don't show your function bound to `rl_attempted_completion_function` as you really should)</sup>

You probably should also use the `rl_line_buffer`, `rl_point` , `rl_end` global variables (modified by `readline`, you want only read access to them).

Read carefully (and several times) the chapter on [custom completers](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_44.html).

BTW, you almost certainly should use `start`  and `end`  arguments to `dv_complete_func`  (assuming you put that in `rl_attempted_completion_function`)

NB. I did experiment around these ideas in my (defunct) [minil](https://github.com/bstarynk/minil) project on github. Sadly all comments and variables there are in French (because it was written to convince a French retired AI researcher). And yes, `readline` API is *very* baroque (and you also should study the source code of programs using it, notably GNU bash). Maybe you should consider using some other library... (look into [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17982633/841108) question and other libraries)

Comment: I have added the code snippet just now. Can you please check it once?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will definitely read the chapter you mentioned. I have 2 questions:
1.My major doubt is from where will the variable names be picked? For autocompletion of functions, I have an array "vfunclist" to be traversed. But for variables already declared/defined, I'm not sure what list should be traversed to list them on auto completion.
2. Can you suggest any better library that I can use?

Comment: The variable names will be picked only by the function *you have written*. What that function does is up to you.