# Can GNU Readline handle multiple streams?

Tags: c++, c, linux, telnet, readline

I'm building a telnet application which uses `GNU Readline` to handle console input. Current implementation forks a new child for every new client connection - this assigns one `readline` instance for each child process.

Fork-type network servers are not the most efficient, so I'd like to use poll/epoll instead, but for that `readline` would have to be configured to work with multiple stream buffers and history, one for each client connection.

I read the `GNU readline` documentation in search of such configuration, but didn't find it. Is this possible, or is there some kind of `readline` alternative that would eneble this feature? Shall I give up this idea?

Comment: Worrying about fork efficiency in an interactive application? What are you trying to do with it, press a billion keys per second? Having said that, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982633/lightweight-gnu-readline-alternative)

Comment: Maybe you right. I think forking is efficient enough, my concerns about this method come from *best practices* in building network servers, I read a lot that poll/epoll is the method of best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readline is documented to read specifically *from the terminal*.  It has no documented mechanism to maintain state for multiple inputs at the same time, and you're already on thin ice using it to read from a stream that is not, in fact, a terminal.

Moreover, the semantics of `readline` do not match a multiplex style service because on each call it blocks until it can read a complete line.  This is simply not a viable alternative, nor would be any work-alike that has similar line-at-a-time blocking behavior.

Comment: Thank's for this answer, I think this resolves my doubts. I'll just stay with what I have implemented already.
By the way `GNU readline` provides a way of calling it in non-blocking way, it's `rl_callback_read_char`.